# Tool to create the schema.xml for a SharePoint 2010 List Template and Instance in VS2010

Tags: windows

I wanted to create a list template and instance from within visual studio 2010 to easily incorporate some lists into a WSP.  However, I would rather create the lists in a manner which is similar to the SharePoint 2010 GUI for creating lists rather than editing the xml manually.  I've looked at using powershell to try and export an existing SharePoint 2010 list to a format which I can just copy and past the xml but that causes a lot of issues with stuff such as all the GUID's being the same and copying way more than I need.  So if you know of any tools that would let me create a list and just spit out the stuff for creating the Schema.xml and even elements.xml that would be perfect!